# Graphhopper demo project doesn't work on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation, graphhopper

I tried to work on Graphhopper demo project on Android Studio, which i found here: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/master/android

After the Gradle building i got this error:
Error:Failed to resolve: com.graphhopper:graphhopper:0.6-SNAPSHOT

Now Android Studio cannot resolve symbols for Graphhopper classes.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.graphhopper.android"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    /* CGIARProvider refers to java.awt
     * Helper7 refers to java.lang.management
     * HeightTile refers to javax.imageio and java.awt
     * OSMElement refers to javax.xml.stream
     */
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}
}

/** only necessary if you need to use latest SNAPSHOT
configurations.all {
// check for updates every build
resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
**/

dependencies {
compile(group: 'com.graphhopper', name: 'graphhopper', version: '0.6-SNAPSHOT') {
   exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
   exclude group: 'org.openstreetmap.osmosis', module: 'osmosis-osm-binary'
   exclude group: 'org.apache.xmlgraphics', module: 'xmlgraphics-commons'
}

compile group: 'org.mapsforge', name: 'mapsforge-core', version: '0.5.2'
compile group: 'org.mapsforge', name: 'mapsforge-map', version: '0.5.2'
compile group: 'org.mapsforge', name: 'mapsforge-map-android', version: '0.5.2'
compile group: 'org.mapsforge', name: 'mapsforge-map-reader', version: '0.5.2'

compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-android', version: '1.7.12'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.12'
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It happens because `com.graphhopper:graphhopper:0.6-SNAPSHOT` is not in the central maven (or jcenter).

You can check all versions [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.graphhopper%22%20AND%20a%3A%22graphhopper%22).

The last stable version is **0.5.0**

If you want to use the `snapshot versions` you have to add a repositoryin your `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    jcenter() 
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
```

Here the [snapshot versions.](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/graphhopper)

Comment: Another possibility is to build it locally and include the uncommented resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor